# Trying to Retrieve image in Mysql database in c# but mysql show error that "parameter is not valid"

Tags: c#, mysql, database, image, winforms

I am working on an application where I need to upload and retrieve an image in the database, not image path. When I upload an image in the database, it stores it in 13B, and when I retrieve it, MySQL shows an error that **"Parameter is not valid"**. Please help I am stuck in this problem from a week.

Code for uploading the image to the database

```
Image temp = new Bitmap(path);
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
temp.Save(strm, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
ImageByteArray = strm.ToArray();
string query = "INSERT INTO image_table(image_id,image_data)VALUES(2,'"+ImageByteArray+"')";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Code for downloading the image from database

```
string Qqquery = "SELECT image_data from image_table WHERE image_id=1";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Qqquery, connection);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    Byte[] bindata = (Byte[])dataReader["image_data"];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bindata);
    Image dimg = Image.FromStream(ms);
    pictureBox2.Image = dimg;
}
dataReader.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading SQL Varbinary Blob from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527782/reading-sql-varbinary-blob-from-database) (among many others)

Comment: Sorry Sir ! but my question is different. Please read my code and tell me that  am i  doing in right way or not.

Comment: Of what type is `image_data` in the database? Many database engines require something other than a string when adding a BLOB type, for instance.

Comment: i have blob data type in database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save picturebox image into mysql database without imagepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951318/how-to-save-picturebox-image-into-mysql-database-without-imagepath)